# How to install Firefox "Stylish" css file?

Tags: css, firefox, stylish

I wrote a css file that is for a private project I am working on, and I am wondering if there's any way to load it into Firefox's Stylish menu without copying and pasting the code?

I thought about putting it on userstyles.org, but like I said, this is a private project and I don't want it available for anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "userContent.css" for Firefox. For more information check out [Customizing Mozilla](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#userContent).

EDIT: To make the stylesheet site-specific take a look at [Firefox Hack: Notes about site specific stylesheets](http://web-professor.net/wp/2008/05/22/firefox-hack-notes-about-site-specific-stylesheets/)